# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '...'

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to install a few packages (`beautifulsoup4` and `requests`) for a project.

I installed these packages by running these commands in the terminal on macOS:

```
pip3 install beautifulsoup4
pip3 install requests
```

both did install successfully.

Now if I open my project in PyCharm, I can import the modules by using:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
```

Both packages are imported successfully and can be used in my code.
To be sure everything was installed correctly, I looked at the `venv/lib/Python3.10` folder. `beautifulsoup4-4.10.0.dist-info`, `bs4`, `requests` and `requests-2.27.1.dist-info` are present.

However, when I run the CGI script (Python), I get the following error in the terminal:

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'
```

Even when I open a new terminal window and run the following commands:

```
python3
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

it runs fine without any errors.
The same issue happens for the `requests` package.

I also ran `pip3 install bs4` but that also didn't fix anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what caused the issue. bs4 and requests were both installed correctly but in my CGI script, I used the wrong Python path. I had to change `#!/usr/bin/python3` to the path that `which python3` gave me.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend to always install packages using `python3 -m pip install <name_of_the_package>`. In this way you can be sure that you are using the correct pip.

To make sure that the python you a using really has the packages installed, try `python3 -m pip list`.

If all is good, check if the python interpreter the pycharm is using in your project is the right one.

It sounds to me that in pycharm you're using a virtual environment, but when you are using python3 at the terminal, you a using the main installation.